# Access data by curl on Jhistrer 5.10 with OAuth2 and Keyclock

Tags: java, spring, curl, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I have an problem with the JHipster 5.1.0 and OAuth2 with Keycloak, if anyone can help me, I appreciate so much.

I created a default jhipster project (Monolithic, Angular 6, OAuth 2.0 / OIDC Authentication with Keycloak) and I don`t maked any changes in the generated code source. I only config the PostgreSQL and generated an entity.

I init the project by "./mvnw" and the Docker image by docker-compose -f "src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up", and I loged and acessed all data of the project on the web.

Until here everthing is ok.

But I need to access the data by curl. This is my problem.

I generated the token use this: `curl -X POST web_app:web_app@localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read"`

But I can't access any data using this token.

For example, I tried access my data using many variations of this: `curl  ocalhost:8080/api/organizacaos -H "Authorization: Bearer $GENERATED_TOKEN_HERE"`

But ever the response is :

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Unauthorized",
  "status" : 401,
  "detail" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/api/organizacaos",
  "message" : "error.http.401"
}
```

Anyone ca help me?

Thanks for all.

Comment: The JHipster API secured by Keycloak auth uses Cookies for authentication, not bearer tokens

Comment: Ok. But do you know any method to access the data using the REST API with authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to use curl with JHipster OAuth2 apps and avoid dealing with cookies is to add a ResourceServer configuration that can read your bearer token.  This is done in the [Ionic](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic) and [React Native](https://github.com/ruddell/ignite-jhipster) JHipster clients and can be applied here.

[Copy this file](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/generator-jhipster-ionic/blob/64dd324ce4a363b71299cb083acdace274c39e45/generators/app/templates/src/main/java/package/config/ResourceServerConfiguration.java) into your Java config package, the important lines which add the RequestHeaderRequestMatcher for the Authorization header are below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

....

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
....
            .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
....
```

Then you can get a token like you described and make requests to secured APIs:

```
# get access token
curl -X POST web_app:web_app@localhost:9080/auth/realms/jhipster/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read"

# request to a secured API
curl localhost:8080/api/account -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Ruddell. I improve your  idea and make what I needed.